# Node js check if user id is in array

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to validate who can do a PUT request on a document.

I have a field that indicates who created the document. If the user created it he/she can edit it and this part is working correctly.

I also have an array of user ids that should also be able to edit but I can't seem to be able to check if the current user is in this array and therefore I can't edit the document.

Here's one document:

```
    {
        "teachers": ["5c740f96e0d6b10016801daa"],
        "_id": "5cd552b179b1b30016c4c0e9",
        "date": "2019-05-10T10:30:09.978Z",
        "name": "prof",
        "goal": "goal",
        "activity": {
            "affective_objectives": [],
            "social_objectives": [],
            "_id": "5cd552b179b1b30016c4c0ea",
            "learning_objectives": [
                {
                    "_id": "5cd552b179b1b30016c4c0eb",
                    "knowledge_category": "Factual",
                    "behaviour": "teste",
                    "subject_matter": "asdas",
                    "conditions": "",
                    "degree": ""
                }
            ],
            "description": "des",
            "subject": "subj",
            "delivery_mode": "teste",
            "interaction": "teste",
            "scope": "teste",
            "age": 5,
            "feedback_use": "High",
            "interrelationship": "High",
            "motivation": "High",
            "participation": "High",
            "performance": "None"
        },
        "project_manager": "5cb48f6a169a9b0016d34dac",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

And my PUT function:

```
function edit(req, res) {

  let query = {
    _id : req.params.id
  };

  Projeto.findById(query)
  .then(async (projeto) =>  {

    if(!projeto) {
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'not_found', message: 'This project doesn\'t exist.'});
    }

    if ( (projeto.project_manager != req.user._id) && (projeto.teachers.indexOf(req.user._id) != -1) )  {
      return res.status(403).json({error: 'forbidden', message: 'You can\'t edit this project.'});
    } else {
      await Projeto.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body, {new: true});
      res.json({ message: 'Project successfully edited.'});
    }



  })
  .catch(utils.handleError(req, res));

}
```

If I try to do a PUT request with the project_manager user everything works but with the user in "teachers" I get the error message that I can't edit.

What's the correct way to verify that here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is **not in teachers array** the `indexOf()` method will return -1.
So, you need to check if it's the case for you:

```
function edit(req, res) {

  let query = {
    _id : req.params.id
  };

  Projeto.findById(query)
  .then(async (projeto) =>  {

    if(!projeto) {
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'not_found', message: 'This project doesn\'t exist.'});
    }

    if ( (projeto.project_manager != req.user._id) && (projeto.teachers.indexOf(req.user._id) === -1) )  {
      return res.status(403).json({error: 'forbidden', message: 'You can\'t edit this project.'});
    } else {
      await Projeto.findOneAndUpdate(query, req.body, {new: true});
      res.json({ message: 'Project successfully edited.'});
    }



  })
  .catch(utils.handleError(req, res));

}
```

**TLDR**:
Replace `projeto.teachers.indexOf(req.user._id) != -1` by `projeto.teachers.indexOf(req.user._id) === -1`

Comment: Yes you're right, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.